# Error en uso de try-catch en c# Index Out Of Range Exception

Tags: c#, excepciones

Estoy viendo excepciones en c#, y tengo un problema con el siguiente código:

```
try
{
    huesped.Agregar_consumo(RepositorioConsumos.Consumos[opcion_servicio - 1]);
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("Elegió un número para un servicio que no existe");
}
```

El código trata de agarrar el error cuando yo pongo un número que está fuera de una lista, es decir si quiero agarrar en la lista el servicio 10 y este no existe porqué está fuera de su rango, me debe avisar ya que ocurre el error: IndexOutOfRangeException

Ese código si funciona, pero si lo cambio por este:

```
try
{
    huesped.Agregar_consumo(RepositorioConsumos.Consumos[opcion_servicio - 1]);
}
catch(IndexOutOfRangeException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Elegió un número para un servicio que no existe");
}
```

En el cual específico en el catch cuál excepción quiero agarrar, no funciona el código y si provoco el error el programa se cierra y me avisa evidentemente del error. ¿Por qué sucede esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try
{
    huesped.Agregar_consumo(RepositorioConsumos.Consumos[opcion_servicio - 1]);
}
catch(IndexOutOfRangeException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Esta es una excepción de array");
}
catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Esta es una excepción de IList<T>");
}
```

Así que deberías revisar, si tienes una lista, debes usar el segundo catch y no el primero.

Comment: Gracias, esta era la respuesta :)

Answer (score 0):

Esto se debe a que le debes de poner cual excepción debe cachar, cuál debe manejar, si no se lo pones el programa no sabe que excepción va a tratar ni como manejarla

Si no sabes que excepción va a lanzar puede poner

```
catch(Exception)
```

Esto cachará (atrapará) todas las excepciones posibles